# Sorting a JSONArray string by its date field YYYY-MM-DD hh-mm-ss.sss

Tags: java, json, sorting, date

I have a JSONArray formatted as a string like this:

```
[{"2016-11-09 19:01:59.649":"someone@email.com::example message"},
{"2016-11-09 19:01:05.542":"someone@email.com::another example"},
{"2016-11-09 19:02:01.394":"someother@gmail.com::another one"}]
```

Is there some efficient way to sort all the JSON objects in chronological order?

Comment: I'd never keep the date field as the key in a `JSONObject`. I think that will mess up on how you are going to use this.

Comment: @Andrew: how many objects do you want to sort?

Comment: @walkeros up to 200 objects, not much more than that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you have only one entry in your `JSONObject` instances, you could:

1. Extract the `JSONObject` instances from the `JSONArray`,
2. Sort the array of `JSONObject` by comparing the first key of the `JSONObject`s,
3. Then create a new `JSONArray` or re-set values in the old `JSONArray`.

Something like this:

```
// Build the source JSONArray
JSONArray array = new JSONArray();
array.put(
    new JSONObject("{\"2016-11-09 19:01:59.649\":\"someone@email.com::example message\"}")
);
array.put(
    new JSONObject("{\"2016-11-09 19:01:05.542\":\"someone@email.com::another example\"}")
);
array.put(
    new JSONObject("{\"2016-11-09 19:02:01.394\":\"someother@gmail.com::another one\"}")
);

// Extract the JSONObjects
JSONObject[] objects = new JSONObject[array.length()];
for (int i = 0; i < objects.length; i++) {
    objects[i] = array.getJSONObject(i);
}
// Sort the array of JSONObjects
Arrays.sort(
    objects,
    (JSONObject o1, JSONObject o2) ->
        ((String)o1.keys().next()).compareTo((String)o2.keys().next())
);
// Build a new JSONArray from the sorted array
JSONArray array2 = new JSONArray();
for (JSONObject o : objects) {
    array2.put(o);
}
System.out.println(array2);
```

**Output:**

```
[{"2016-11-09 19:01:05.542":"someone@email.com::another example"},{"2016-11-09 19:01:59.649":"someone@email.com::example message"},{"2016-11-09 19:02:01.394":"someother@gmail.com::another one"}]
```

Comment: Thanks, it looks pretty good! I will try it out in a few moments and accept it as the correct answer as soon as it works.